# intellij- where are the artifacts?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am building jars using build artifacts from the menu.
In "Project structure" I have in the artifacts - output directory.
When the build stops - it doesn't say anything is wrong and it doesn't put the jar file in the output directory.
Are there readable logs for the artifact build?
Where is the jar folder set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Artifact output directory configuration defines where your artifacts will be placed. Check [idea.log](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181) for possible problems.